# Polymer starter kit project showing empty web page

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit, google-web-component

I have created my first polymer-cli project using "polymer-2-starter-kit" and project is successfully created but after serving and opening it in browser it just shows an empty screen both on opera and chrome.

**UPDATE**

following are errors I can see in the console.

[image: console errors]

Comment: What errors do you get in console?

Comment: please see the updated version of the question @Ofisora

Comment: Your bower components are missing. Can you check the project folder if it is missing do bower install.

Comment: thnks @Ofisora please write it as an answer so i can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bower components are missing.

You have to install the components as well.

Just do `bower install` and your project will work.